# Problem while Ubuntu starting

Tags: lubuntu

The problem I saw today.
I googled it, but didn't find the answer.
Someone has similar and solved it, but he had problems with AMD

I have pretty old PC. ~12years. Changed only ram.
It works fine with windows and linux.
But today I saw this problem.
Screenshots 1. And after some time 2.
I restarted it and see 3. and Ubuntu launched successfully.

1. https://ibb.co/5jJsXcz
2. https://ibb.co/VprJsfz
3. https://ibb.co/ns11Ntw

Comment: So right now you have no problem. What's the question here?

Comment: Sometimes you get episodes like this, more often if the computer has not been shut down normally. The recovering journal message is normal when this happens. There is nothing here to indicate you have an enduring problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.